# return None in the end of the program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

In the question they asked me to pick up numbers from the user and then solve a quadratic equation.
I did it and check it on Python Tutor and every time it return me None, why is that?

```
def quadratic_equation(a,b,c):
import math
if a == 0:
    print("The parameter 'a' may not equal 0")
elif (b**2) - (4 * a * c) < 0:
    print("The equation has no solutions")
else:
### x1 mean with +
    x1 = ((-b) + (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a)
### x2 mean with - 
    x2 = ((-b) - (math.sqrt((b**2) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a)
    if x1 and x2 is not None:
        return (f"The equation has 2 solutions: {x1} and {x2}")
    elif x1 is None:
        return (f"The equation has 1 solution: {x2} ")
    elif x2 is None:
        return (f"The equation has 1 solution: {x1} ")

def quadratic_equation_user_input():
numbers = (input("Insert coefficients a, b, and c: "))
num = []
for i in numbers.split():
    try:
        num.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
a = num[0]
b = num[1]
c = num[2]
quadratic_equation(a,b,c)


print(quadratic_equation_user_input())
```

Comment: Since you're using Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning, and that badly indented Python does not make sense and cannot be run. Rather than making us try and guess what your correctly indented code looks like, please [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: Last line in a method is not the return value. You need to `return quadratic_equation(a, b, c)` explicitly. Python as you have experienced will `return None` if there isn’t an explicit return.

Comment: I tried to indented it here but I don't know how to do it the tab dosent work here, I my doc I did it well

Comment: Use spaces rather than tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quadratic_equation_user_input` calls `quadratic_equation` and ignores its return value, thus it returns `None` which is the default return value.

```
# Call function but ignore return value
quadratic_equation(a,b,c)

# No return in caller function -> default to None
# ....
```

You probably meant

```
return quadratic_equation(a,b,c)
```

at the end of `quadratic_equation_user_input`.